# Next JS to convert context.query into a string

Tags: next.js

I am trying to create a slug function but I cannot lookup the slug because I cannot convert my context.query into a string:

```
  
export async function getServerSideProps(context){
  const { API } = withSSRContext(context);
  const VendorData = await API.graphql({
    query: getVendorBySlug,
    variables: { 
      slug: context.query
    }
  });


  return {
    props: {
      data: VendorData,
    }
  };
}
```

I receive the error message -
`` Error: Error serializing `.data` returned from `getServerSideProps` in "/v/[slug]". Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use `null` or omit this value. ``

Comment: `context.query` is an object of the query string passed in the page's URL. What exactly do you need from it?

Comment: I want to get string of the slug to pass to my graphql query to look up the data.

Comment: Log `context.query` value to the console and see how you can access the value you need from it.

Comment: I just get "object"